# How can I dynamically apply predicates from a list of registered predicates in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an `IQueryable<T>`. And `T` is a generic type parameter that is  `where T : class, IEntity, new()`.

Now I have this code that registers a list of predicates to be applied dynamically on this iqueryable:

```
private static Dictionary<int, Action<IQueryable<IEntity>>> queryAugmenters = new Dictionary<int, Action<IQueryable<IEntity>>>();

public static List<Action<IQueryable<IEntity>>> QueryAugmenters
{
    get
    {
        return queryAugmenters.Values.ToList();
    }
}

public static void AddQueryAugmenter(Action<IQueryable<IEntity>> queryAugmenter)
{
    var hash = queryAugmenter.GetHashCode();
    if (queryAugmenters.ContainsKey(hash))
    {
        return;
    }
    queryAugmenters.Add(hash, queryAugmenter);
}
```

And this is one place that I register an augmenter:

```
DynamicQuery.AddQueryAugmenter(queryable =>
{
    if (Config.HasMultipleLocales)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Where(i => ((ILocale)i).LocaleId == Config.LocaleId);
    }
});
```

So, basically I'm seeing the settings and if this project is multi-lingual, I add a predicate to the `IQueryable<T>`.

This is the code that I use to apply augmenters on a given query:

```
private static IQueryable<T> AugmentQuery(IQueryable<T> queryable)
{
    foreach (var queryAugmenter in DataAccessConfig.QueryAugmenters)
    {
        queryAugmenter.Invoke(queryable);
    }

    return queryable;
}
```

The problem is that it does not work.

It compiles, it runs, but no **where clause** is added to the query that is sent to the database.

If I move the code, it works:

```
private static IQueryable<T> AugmentQuery(IQueryable<T> queryable)
{
    foreach (var queryAugmenter in DataAccessConfig.QueryAugmenters)
    {
        queryAugmenter.Invoke(queryable);
    }

    // this code works here
    if (Config.HasMultipleLocales)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Where(i => ((ILocale)i).LocaleId == Config.LocaleId);
    }

    return queryable;
}
```

What do I miss here?

Comment: You have to invoke the action predicate inside AddQueryAugmenter not inside AugmentQuery.

Comment: `Action<IQueryable<IEntity>>` is not a predicate. A predicate is `public delegate bool Predicate<in T>(T obj)`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=net-7.0

Comment: with action like `x=>x=x+1` you obviously are only changing local `x` (local for expression) not input parameter of action ... in other words `Action<IQueryable<IEntity>>` doesn't change state of passed argument

Comment: @GHDevOps, `AddQueryAugmenter` is there to register augmenters. It does not run a query.

Comment: besides if you are using EF it doesn't make sens ... since you are using Action.Invoke it would not be able to work with Linq to SQL translation

Comment: @Selvin, I'm not defining a local X there. I'm re-assining to the input parameter.

Comment: No, you are not ... paramter is local variable

Comment: You probably need to execute `queryable.Where(x => Augmenter(x))` where `Augmenter` is an actual `Predicate<T>` and not `Action<IQueryable<IEntity>>`.

Comment: @Selvin, please inform me how? Because when there is no `var` or any variable declaration syntax, then there is no local variable. And in a lambda, the input parameter is  just like the ordinary parameter of a function. If I'm wrong please give me a link to read more.

Comment: @Dialecticus, if I do that, then it means that I have already added a where clause. In that case, the `Augmenter` is already added. I want to be able to add it conditionally. I lose the possiblity of using `if` statement in that case.

Comment: if paramteter is not `ref` or `out` they are always passed by value ... yeah, if it's not a value type then the value is reference ... but still value ... so it's local reference and if you asign something to it you are asigning only locally ...pretty simple

Comment: Check for null, and if null return true. Something like `queryable.Where(x => Augmenter is null ? true : Augmenter(x))`. But this might not translate to database query... Maybe just have two paths of execution.

Comment: `public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);` ... as you see `T obj` is your missing *variable declaration syntax* and it's local in the scope of this delegate

Comment: @Selvin, thank you so much, now I understand. I tried to use `ref` with `Action` delegate, but it seems to be impossible. What options do I have to make it work? Basically I need to register some functions as a list, and loop over them and pass the `IQueryable<T>` to them *by reference* so that they can add where clauses dynamically.

Comment: to make it work even in EF you need to declare predicates as `List<Expression<Func<IEntity, bool>>> predicates = new List<Expression<Func<IEntity, bool>>>();` ... then you may apply them as `foreach(var predicate in predicates) queryable = queryable.Where(predicate);` ...again ... pretty basic ... and again to work in EF you should check `Config.HasMultipleLocales` outside predicate itself as obviously `Config.HasMultipleLocales` will not be translated to SQL code

Comment: @Selvin, that won't work for me. Because I want to be able to apply the `where` clause in Linq dynamically. Instead of looping over predicates and applying them one by one, I need to pass the iqueryable to some other function, and that function can do a lot of things to decide whethere it should add the predicate or not.

Comment: Then it would not work in EF (yeah, sure, you can materialize query ... but then all not filtered data will go to the sql client side) ... I just said that you should do 
    `if (Config.HasMultipleLocales){DynamicQuery.AddQueryAugmenter(i => ((ILocale)i).LocaleId == Config.LocaleId);}` not other way

Comment: @Selvin, the `where` clause is a simple EF translatable predicate. Something like `.Where(i => i.IsActive == true)`. But it should be applied conditionally. For example `if (Config.IsForVipUsersOnly) { queryable = queryable.Where(i => i.IsVipt == true) }`

Comment: ok ... then change `Action<IQueryable<IEntity>>` to `Func<IQueryable<IEntity>, IQueryable<IEntity>>` and return modified query so you could chain it like `queryable = queryAugmenter(queryable);`

Comment: `AddQueryAugmenter(queryable => Config.HasMultipleLocales ?  queryable.Where(i => ((ILocale)i).LocaleId == Config.LocaleId) : queryable);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250585/discussion-between-big-boy-and-selvin).

Answer (score 1):

change your `Action<IQueryable<IEntity>>` fo `Func<IQueryable<IEntity>, IQueryable<IEntity>>` so you would be able to chain calls

then change `AugmentQuery(IQueryable<T> queryable)` to

```
private static IQueryable<T> AugmentQuery(IQueryable<T> queryable)
{
    foreach (var queryAugmenter in DataAccessConfig.QueryAugmenters)
    {
        queryable = queryAugmenter(queryable);
    }

    return queryable;
}
```

And your your curent `DynamicQuery.AddQueryAugmenter`

to

```
queryable => Config.HasMultipleLocales ? queryable.Where(i => ((ILocale)i).LocaleId == Config.LocaleId) : queryable
```

in other words now your `queryAugmenter` should follow

```
queryable =>
{
    if(something)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Where(....);
    }
    return queryable;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you're putting in this. I really appreciate that. But I don't have access to `Config.HasMultipLocales` there. The condition should be encapsulated inside the other augmenter function. I wrote a simpler question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74878424/how-to-pass-iquerayblet-to-an-actioniqueryableientity)