# How to pass IQueryable<T> to an Func<IQueryable<IEntity>>?

Tags: c#

Consider this simple code:

```
// queryable is IQueryable<T>
// where T : class, IEntity, new()
queryable = queryable.Where(i => i.IsVip == true);
```

Now I want to define a function, that takes this queryable as the input, applies the where clause conditionally, and returns the queryable. This other function should be a delegate.

```
Func<WhatHere> OtherFunction = queryable => 
{
  if (Config.IsVip)
  {
    queryable = queryable.Where(i => ((IVip)i).IsVip == true);
  }
  return queryable;
};
queryable = OtherFunction(queryable)
```

How can I do that?

P.S. I'm simplifying [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74877673/how-can-i-dynamically-apply-predicates-from-a-list-of-registered-predicates-in-c).

**Update**

If I use `Func<IQueryable<IEntity>, IQueryable<IEntity>>`, then I get this compile-time error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Models.IEntity>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

If I cast it as

```
queryable = (IQueryable<T>)OtherFunction(queryable)
```

then I get this runtime error:

> 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable1[Models.IEntity]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable1[PostView]'.'

`PostView` is an `IEntity`.

**Update 2**

A friend of mine created a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b4M6M4) for this. Please see it in action.

Comment: Why are you using `IEntity` instead of `TEntity`? `IQueryable<T>` is essentially useless without _concrete_ type information, not interfaces.

Comment: @Dai, I dont understand. An interface is useless when it's used in a generica parameter type definition?

Comment: it is [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) problem I don't belive if you can go easy with this [(in fact i'm pretty sure that it is not possible to solve)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VHx4yz)

Comment: @BigBoy You should edit your question subject: This isn't an `Action<...>` but a `Func<...>`.

Comment: @RemiDespres-Smyth, thank you. My bad. Really tired here. Fixed it.

Comment: @Selvin, please see the fiddle.

Comment: @Dai, can you please see the fildde?

Comment: @BigBoy Sorry, deleted my answer after seeing your edit.  I don't have the time to dig into it currently.

Comment: @marc_s can you see the fiddle?

Comment: @BigBoy your casting error suggests that you don't actually have an `IQueryable<IEntity>`, but an `IQueryable<PostView>`.  If you're always going to be working with `PostView` instances, you can change `OtherFunction`'s signature to use `PostView` instead if `IEntity`.  Problem here is that every `PostView` is an `IEntity`, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: @RemiDespres-Smyth, a lot of classes inherit from `IEntity`. `PostView`, `User`, `Ticket`, `Payment`, `Order`, `Product`, `Page`, `Permission`, etc. I'm trying to create something dynamic here.

Answer (score 2):

Taking your friend's Fiddle as a starting point, try this:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    long Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IVip
{
    bool IsVip { get; set; }
}

public interface Post : IEntity, IVip
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsVip { get; set; }
}

public class Repository<T>
    where T : class, IEntity, new()
{
    public List<T> GetList()
    {
        var query = new List<T>().AsQueryable(); // to mimic the database query
        query = QueryAugmenter<T>.AugmentQuery(query);
        return query.ToList();
    }
}

public static class QueryAugmenter<T>
    where T : IEntity
{
    public static Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> AugmentQuery = query =>
    {
        var someCondition = false; // mimicing the condition
        if (someCondition)
        {
            // This would throw if T does not implement IVip
            //query = query.Where(i => ((IVip)i).IsVip == true);

            // You need to make sure the cast isn't going to throw first
            if (typeof(IVip).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) {
                query = query.Where(i => ((IVip)i).IsVip == true);
            }
        }

        // You might have to do query.AsQueryable<T>() 
        // here, not sure offhand
        return query;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually solved it using dynamic link. I return a string conditionally and if that string is not null or empty, I apply it dynamiclly.